# Tkinter label getting cut off (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am creating a password generating using tkinter, specifically the [customtkinter](https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/) module. I have created a button that generates a random password and displays it in a label. the password length is a random in ranging from 8-12 characters. There is this issue where the password gets cut off and I have tried many options to fix it. Heres my code and some examples. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import random

##---initializing window---##
app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title("Password Generator")
width = 800
height = 600
app.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

##---Button mapping---##
def PwrdGenerator():
    Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%&"
    shuffled = ''.join(random.sample(Char,len(Char)))
    p_length = random.randint(8,13)
    password = ''
    for i in range(p_length):
        password+= random.choice(shuffled)
    return label.configure(text=password)

##TODO save function
##---Button1 mapping---##
def save():
   pass

##--- Label---##
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app,text="Passwords",corner_radius=8,fg_color="gray75",text_color='black')
label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=tkinter.CENTER)


##---Button1---##
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app,text="Generate",command=PwrdGenerator)
button.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.25,anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

##---Button2---##
button1= customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app,text="Save",command=save)
button1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8,anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

app.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Use monospaced font on `label`.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the CTkLabel implementation.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Im pretty new to python and programming in general so I wasn't sure if it was an issue I was causing or I could fix